# PHPmailer works with Xampp but failed with Php CLI

Tags: xampp, phpmailer

I am using PHpmailer to send emails. It is working fine with browsers on Xampp. However when I try to run it through PHP CLI it gives the error:

> SMTP connect():failed

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's likely your two PHP configurations are different - compare the settings in a web page that runs `<?php phpinfo();` with `php -i` on a command line, and look at the `.ini` files it's using in particular.

Comment: Apparently Php --ini gives me following result                             C:\xampp\php>php --ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: C:\windows
Loaded Configuration File:         C:\xampp\php\php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)

Comment: OK, check the output from `php -m` as well, it will show you what extensions are enabled.

Comment: I checked the php modules but cannot find mail

Comment: There is no mail module, that's not what you're looking for - you're looking to see what differences there are between your two PHP environments. Also try setting `$mail->SMTPDebug = 4;` and see if the output tells you anything useful, pick out the interesting parts and add them them to your question.

Comment: Thanks Synchro for help. It turns out that Xampp doesn't have different php.ini files. However, after making changes for smtp parameters in php.ini solved my problem.

Comment: That is strange because PHPMailer does not do anything controlled by those settings if you use its own SMTP class. It would help if you posted the exact changes you made to clarify.